# JSON doesn't render log stack trace

Tags: node.js, express

This is how im setting up log4js.

```
import log4js from 'log4js';
const logger = log4js.getLogger();
log4js.configure({
  appenders: { log: { type: 'file', filename: 'logTofile.json' } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['log'], level: 'ALL' } }
});
const app = express();
```

this is how im retrieving the json

```
app.get('/logtofile', (req, res, next) => {
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('logTofile.json'); 
  const log = JSON.parse(rawdata); 
  res.json(log); 
});
```

this is the output it gives out on the **logTofile.json**

[image]

Render this

[image]

is their anyway we i can get the log json to render as it should in the logTofile.json file ?

Comment: Look at this layout package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js-json-layout.

Comment: thx, will look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `fs.readFileSync('logTofile.json');` will read in a buffer by default.

The output you see is the `JSON.parse` of a Buffer object.

You must pass `'utf8'` in to `fs.readFileSync` as the second parameter.

```
fs.readFileSync('logTofile.json'); // Buffer
fs.readFileSync('logTofile.json', 'utf8'); // String
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options